# Docker - denied: Your Authorization Token has expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I am getting this error when I try to push a docker container
denied: Your Authorization Token has expired.

I had aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1, I tried the hack someone posted here where you take out the https none have worked.

When I run aws ecr get-login ...  I get the code I copy and paste it and get a successful message but when I try to push my docker container I get the denied: Your Authorization Token has expired.  I am using docker version Docker version 17.03.1-ce.  Any Ideas what I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you pushing with the same user that has been logged in? I mean, are you mixing with sudo commands?

Answer (score 7):

Please use following command combination:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <REGION> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <AWS_ACCOUNT_NO>.dkr.ecr.<AWS_REGION_NAME>.amazonaws.com
```

Quoting from the documentation:

"This command retrieves and displays an authentication token using the GetAuthorizationToken API that you can use to authenticate to an Amazon ECR registry. You can pass the authorization token to the login command of the container client of your preference, such as the Docker CLI. "

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html

Comment: Finally. This one worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

@Robert's comment (see comment to the question itself) was enough for me. The mistake was that

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <REGION> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <AWS_ACCOUNT_NO>.dkr.ecr.<AWS_REGION_NAME>.amazonaws.com
```

was not on sudo, but the actual docker push was.

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be the aws-cli version. The version of this CLI tool which seems to be a Python package can be seen in `aws --version`. I encountered this error for the version `aws-cli/2.1.29`, but not in the older version `aws-cli/1.18.40`.

The "aws ecr get-login" command is [deprecated](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/735), Amazon recommends to use "aws ecr get-login-password" instead.